# Change order status from email

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I added email template to notify admin when an order is placed in Magento.

I need to add a button or link in the email to allow the admin to change order status to processing without going to the back-end just from the email.

How can this be done?

Comment: add a variable to the email URL and same on Magento with a token that authenticates the request and updates the record?

Comment: can you know how to start in it as i am new in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the status's you can use

```
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
```

Code for updating the status.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid, 'increment_id');
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
$order->save();
```

Above code will update all the status's except COMPLETE Status. As Order becomes complete only when invoice and shipment is created. Once invoice and shipment is created order will automatically changed to Complete.

so for that you can use below code.

Create Invoice

```
$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice()
                 ->setTransactionId($order->getId())
                 ->addComment($comment)
                 ->register()
                 ->pay();

$transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                 ->addObject($invoice)
                 ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transaction_save->save();
create shipmnet

$itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
$shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
$shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);
```

Comment: Thanks , will this codes added only to the email template?

Comment: To complete this process, first create a button into email template with custom URL ex: domain.com/controller/action/order_id/123. Whenever click on the created button then custom URL will be called where you will get order_id parameter. Using this order_id you can run further code which I have mentioned above to change the order status.